# Batch file script to convert PDFs and image files to TIFF

Tags: batch-file

I need to convert multiple PDFs, and image files (JPG, GIF, etc.) within a certain folder to TIFF and then move the TIFF to a different folder and put the original in an "ARCHIVE" folder (within the first folder). This will run every 5-10 minutes using a scheduled task within Windows.

I have been using a program called Ghostscript which works great, the command line I am using for converting a PDF for example is:

```
gswin64.exe -o test03.tiff -r720x720 -g6120x7920 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 test.pdf
```

Can anybody help me out with a script to do the above?

Comment: Does ghostscript allow you to operate on an entire folder?

Comment: It looks like Ghostscript can create the TIFF file in any directory, it is just needed to specify the TIFF file with full path enclosed in double quotes. And the command to use in a batch file to do something on all files matching a pattern is __FOR__. Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` to get output the help of this command. You need additionally the command __MOVE__ with help displayed on running `move /?` in a command prompt window. Code for your task can be found already on Stack Overflow hundreds of times. So use the search for examle with __[batch-file] move for__.

Answer (score 0):

To convert image to tiff without external binaries you can use [**`convImg.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imageProcessing/convImg.bat).It still not completed (I need to add help message and some checks) but it is working.Accepts two arguments source image and the target one and the format is taken by the extension:

```
call convImg.bat "C:\putin_gay_clown.jpg" "C:\putin_gay_clown.tiff"
```

To complete your script you can use:

```
@echo off
::: !!! CHANGE THE LOCATIONS BELLOW !!!
set "pics=c:\pics"
set "tiff_folder=c:\tiffs"

for %%a in ("%pics%\*jpg" "%pics%\*gif" "%pics%\*png" "%pics%\*bpm") do (
   call convImg.bat "%%~fa" "%tiff_folder%\%%~na.tiff"
)
```

As for the converting a `pdf` to `tiff` I don't think this is possible without external tool.